# MERGE in pyspark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a requirement where in my adls gen2 silver table i have to update one of the column based on a condition when the case is matched and if not then it will be default value. The code i am using is as below

```
spark.sql(f"""MERGE INTO qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change 
USING (SELECT * FROM material) latestChange 
ON latestChange.s3_file_location = qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.s3_file_location 
  and latestChange.serialnum = qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.serialnum 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.materialnum 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.materialnum = DEFAULT  
""")
```

"materialnum' is the field that i have to update and "material" is the temp view i have created on top of the Dataframe. "ael_events_supply_change" is the silver delta table that i am trying to update.

But the above code is throwing me error. Can someone help me what i am missing here.

Comment: add the error message

Comment: missing EQ in line no 1

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify to which value it should be set in the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.materialnum` -> this should be something like:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET qa.pigeon_silver.ael_events_supply_change.materialnum = latestChange.materialnum
```

P.S. the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` also may not be correct - if `DEFAULT` is a string, then it should be in the single quotes

Comment: I'm not convinced OPs `when not matched` clause is valid either.

Comment: Agree. But it’s not clear if DEFAULT is a string, or just a placeholder…

Comment: so basically the ask is when not matched do nothing ; no insert will happen. so that i am trying to write as "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT * WHERE 1=2" . Or there is a better approach to handle this scenario where i don't want to insert anything in case of not matched.

Comment: If you don’t need it, just omit it - it’s not required. See examples here: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html